# how i put the data that come using ajax call in a php code that include a blade template inside <tbody> tag?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is the  structure :

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($user_bookings['day'] as $user_booking)
                                            @if(isset( $user_booking['name']))
                                            @include('Dashboard::user-booking',                    ['user_booking'=>$user_booking])
                                            @endif
                                            @endforeach
</tbody>
```

this code was working when the data were come when i log in ,but it takes a long time to load the dashboard page, so i need to retrieve the data when the dashboard document is ready ,to perform ajax call .

now i performed a successful ajax call ,but i don't know how to put the data that comes with a json format inside this tbody tag ,any one have any clue how i cam implement this .

this is my ajax it is not complete ,because i dont know what to do .

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getuserbookings', 
        type: 'GET',
        

        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success bro",data);
           

        },

        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('AJAX request failed:', error);
        }


    });

    
});

</script>
```

the project is running using php laravel .

i on the last step ,which is to put the data that comes by the ajax call in the tbody that contains php code and a laravel blade templeat .

Comment: Write some JS which adds the data to the DOM

Comment: how i do that give  a sample code

Comment: Does your ajax call return a html string, or perhaps some json data? It isn't clear. But if you don't even know where to start, your first job needs to be to take some tutorials about basic javascript and functions for altering a web page using javascript. Then you'll have the skills to complete the task